# Output dynamic json as table in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table and data in my database (column "foo" has datatype "json"):

[image]

I would to output the data in "foo" and column as follows:

[image]

There are two important considerations:

- there can be different keys in the json object for each row
- the type of value stored for the same key might a different data type i.e. for row #1, b value is a string, while for row #2, the value of b is a number.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: a) you can't have a different number of columns each time you run a query.  b) all values in a column must have the same datatype c) all rows must have the same number of columns. What you are trying to achieve is simply not possible.